# How do I check when when a diagonal line is off the window? Processing

Tags: if-statement, processing, lines, diagonal

I am having trouble figuring out how I can get the line to repeat once it goes off the screen. I tried numerous if statements, but no luck. As of right now, I just have the line goes across, but not the other part I mentioned. Can someone help me.

Sorry, here's a simpler version.

```
float[] speeds = new float[1];
float[] diaxPos = new float[1];
float[] diayPos = new float[1];
float[] dia2xPos = new float[1];
float[] dia2yPos = new float[1];


void setup() {
  size(300, 300);
  diaxPos[0] = 0;
  diayPos[0] = 0;
  dia2xPos[0] = 0;
  dia2yPos[0] = 0;
  speeds[0] = 2;
 }

void draw() {
  background(0);
  stroke(255);


diayPos[0] += speeds[0];
  dia2xPos[0] += speeds[0];



 (diaxPos[0], diayPos[0], dia2xPos[0], dia2yPos[0]);
      }
```

Comment: That's a lot of extra code, can you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead? We don't need all that code for the non-diagonal lines.

Comment: There, I posted the only part of my code I need help with.

Answer (score 0):

Just check whether the line has gone off the screen. In your case, this happens when the X or Y value is greater than 600. Get some grid paper and draw some examples to figure out a pattern.

```
float[] speeds = new float[1];
float[] diaxPos = new float[1];
float[] diayPos = new float[1];
float[] dia2xPos = new float[1];
float[] dia2yPos = new float[1];

void setup() {
  size(300, 300);
  diaxPos[0] = 0;
  diayPos[0] = 0;
  dia2xPos[0] = 0;
  dia2yPos[0] = 0;
  speeds[0] = 2;
}

void draw() {
  background(0);
  stroke(255);

  diayPos[0] += speeds[0];
  dia2xPos[0] += speeds[0];

  if (diayPos[0] > 600) {
    diayPos[0] = 0;
    dia2xPos[0] = 0;
  }

  line(diaxPos[0], diayPos[0], dia2xPos[0], dia2yPos[0]);
}
```